# Unable to nest loops in jmeter test plan

Tags: jmeter

I have a JMeter test plan to do the following:

- Reads a list of domain URLs from a CSV
- visit each
- extract main menu items from each domain
- loop on each menu item

  - visit the menu item

I have a debug sampler and I am able to successfully run the thread group and successfully extract menu items but it fails to go into the last loop.

[image]

Comment: Found the answer already. I had to check the `use "-" before number` checkbox in the  `loop through Non-admin links` section

Comment: you can answer your own question and accept it as the answer. this way we can track which questions need attention and which are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. had to check the `use "-" before number` checkbox in the loop through Non-admin links section as shown in the picture below. 
[image]